# How to make shiny outputs render within every slide of a bootstrap carousel?

Tags: shiny, bootstrap-5

I was trying to implement a [bootstrap5 carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#with-indicators) in a Shiny App. Unfortunately any output (text, table, ..) will not render in any slide expect from the first one. Is there a workaround to make this actually work?

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(theme = bs_theme(version = 5),

 div(id="carouselExampleIndicators", class="carousel slide", `data-bs-ride`="carousel",
     
 div(class="carousel-indicators",
     tags$button(`data-bs-target`="#carouselExampleIndicators", `data-bs-slide-to`="0", class="active", `aria-current`="true", `aria-label`="Slide 1"),
     tags$button(`data-bs-target`="#carouselExampleIndicators", `data-bs-slide-to`="1", `aria-label`="Slide 2")),
         
     div(class = "carousel-inner",
         
     div(class = "carousel-item active",
     div(textOutput(outputId = "txt1"), style = "display: flex; justify-content: center;")),
     
     div(class = "carousel-item",
     div(textOutput(outputId = "txt2"),style = "display: flex; justify-content: center;"))),
         
     tags$button(class="carousel-control-prev", `data-bs-target` = "#carouselExampleIndicators", `data-bs-slide`="prev",
     span(class="carousel-control-prev-icon", `aria-hidden` = "true"),
     span("prev", class="visually-hidden")),
         
     tags$button(class="carousel-control-next", `data-bs-target` = "#carouselExampleIndicators", `data-bs-slide`="next",
     span(class="carousel-control-next-icon", `aria-hidden` = "true"),
     span(class="visually-hidden")))

)

server = function(input, output, session){

    
    output$txt1 = renderText({
       "displayed"
    })
    
    output$txt2 = renderText({
       "not displayed"
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```